# Books on Neurological functions?

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, reference-request, consciousness, neuroanatomy

Are there any books anyone can recommend that do not have any or much in the way of prerequisites but go through the anatomy of the central nervous system while laying out in detail the functions of the various regions of the brain *especially the higher brain*. 
I do not mean a book that merely cuts the brain into brain stem, the mid brain and higher regions like the cortices and then simply divides those regions into a dozen or so further categories. I am looking for something that is a lot more detailed and focuses on the functions of thought, emotions, sensations, perceptions, and memory and the cellular anatomy that goes along with them.

I realize it might be difficult to find a textbook without any prerequisites, so let me say as few prerequisites as possible.

Comment: Cognitive Neuroscience (Gazzinga) is what I would recommend.

Answer (score 3):

Any basic Neuroscience book would suffice, really. For example, a really good and widely used book is

[**Principles of Neural Science**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_Neural_Science) from Kandel *et al*. I read it nearly from cover to cover, and it details the workings of the nervous system from bottom to top. Parts IV to IX are probably most relevant to you:

- Part IV: The Neural Basis of Cognition
- Part V: Perception
- Part VI: Movement
- Part VII: The Unconscious and Conscious Processing of Neural Information
- Part VIII: Development and the Emergence of Behavior
- Part IX: Language, Thought, Affect, and Learning